# Daily log can't be written in due to permissions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've changed my `app.php` configuration to use daily error logs and to only keep 7 of them:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Logging Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
| the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
| you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
|
| Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
|
*/

'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'daily'),
'log_max_files' => 7,
```

However, nothing is being written in these log files because they can't be written in, according to apache's error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/newshub/storage/logs/laravel-2016-07-18.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied'

I tried recursively changing write permissions for both the `storage` and `logs` directories. This worked, but when the next day's error log was created, it no longer had write permissions.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. Each day the file creates and then I am not able to write to that. The problem was with the owner of the file. This should be www-data but it gets created by another user. I run the command

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data /storage
```

and everything works fine.

To solve this problem, I created a crontab to run every day to change the ownership of the newly created file. This was run immediately after the file was generated for that day. This is a short-term fix, but researching on how to get this fixed long term.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GIT to update the codebase on your server?
I have noticed that sometimes when I pull, permissions for some directories are lost, never happened with `logs` directory but worth a look.

As for Laravel goes, this isn't exactly on the framework rather than a server configuration issue.

Comment: Nope, not using git.

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner  with ubuntu or apache based on your OS to storage folder recursively. It will work without any further issues.

example:
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/storage  (based on your current location of storage)

Answer (score -1):

```
cd /var/www/newshub/storage/
chmod -R 0777 logs
```

try these commands with ssh please

Comment: As I said, "I tried recursively changing write permissions for both the storage and logs directories. This worked, but when the next day's error log was created, it no longer had write permissions."

Comment: oh than try to give permission to www-data user ... this may be issue ... 
like sudo chown www-data:www-data -R folder path

Comment: Never try to change permission to 777, rather than try to change owner for security reason